# Generally accepted ways of taming callbacks in Node?

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm just starting with node.js, and am trying to avoid mistakes along the way to the maximum possible extent.  One key pain point is the 'callback hell' problem a lot of node developers run into.

Are there generally-accepted ways now to lessen that burden?  I've heard of the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library and wondered if other solutions are out there.

If I go with ES6 from the start what else can I do to tighten the code; I assume generators are a good place to begin?

Comment: The async library solves a different problem: calling async functions in a loop. For getting out of callback hell there are two strategies: avoid anonymous functions (name your functions then pass that name instead of declaring the function directly as a function argument), use promises. Between the two promises is a bit more popular (or at least more "trendy"). The culture that has grown around javascript prefers anonymous functions for callbacks

Comment: [checkout my answer to a very same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343116/how-to-handle-callbacks-in-a-for-loopnode-js/29349325#29349325). Basically, if you wanna go with plain javascript to avoid the "callback hell" just define all (or at least the bigger ones of) your function outside. Just because a function takes another function as an argument, you don't necessarily have to define it right there as an anonymous function. Define it outside.

Comment: Promises in general are your friend for managing async operations.  I personally use the [Bluebird promise library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) because it has a lot of helpful features built around promises.  While it helps tame callback hell, the real (and not talked about much) benefit of using promises is that robust error handling is much simpler and practical when using promises vs. callbacks.  It is next to impossible to propagate errors using callbacks, but very easy when using promises and promises are throw-safe, but callbacks are not.

Comment: I would say that promises are the place to begin as your most fundamental tool for managing async callbacks, not generators.  Generators may have their place in some types of operations, but only in some and they aren't a general replacement for async callbacks like promises are.

Comment: Here's a pretty good resource on this topic that covers promises, async and generators: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/.  FYI, a Google search for `node.js callback hell` will give you more articles on the topic that you will have time to read.  Plenty written on this topic already.