# console.log() as a callback in response.on()

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the code below, I'm making a simple `get` request with node.js and logging the response to the console. This works perfectly fine, but why? What's happening in the `response.on` section? Why do `console.log` and `console.error` work **without taking any arguments**?

```
var http = require('http')
http.get('http://www.google.com/index.html', function (response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8')
    response.on('data', console.log) // <---
    response.on('error', console.error) // <---
})
```

Comment: console.log as callback will be executed and passed the data of the event

Comment: @Eric where can I find that mentioned in any documentation?

Comment: If `console.log` were a number, you would be able to pass it to a function. Maybe you’d call it `x` in the function and use `x + 5`. In the same way, when `console.log` is a function, you can still pass it to another function and use `x()`. JavaScript has [first-class functions](http://helephant.com/2008/08/19/functions-are-first-class-objects-in-javascript/).

Comment: No Idea. I guess you could create a dummy class and test it, see if it passes something to it by default.Actually, I believe it receives the 1st argument.

Comment: shmuli - It's not the `console.log()` documentation you need to be looking at, it is the `response.on()` documentation that should tell you what arguments will be passed to the function you provide as a callback. You can supply *any* function there and it will be called with the data (or error information).

Comment: http://www.codedisqus.com/CiVjggVekg/node-stream-not-passing-callback-function-a-value.html

Answer (score 1):

They ***do*** take arguments. They take arguments as whatever the `response.on`'s callback provides them with.

Passing the functions inline as **anonymous** function:

```
response.on('data', function(data){ // anonymous function passed inline
    console.log(data);
});
```

is the same as defining them outside and passing them **by name**:

```
...
response.on('data', callback)
...
function callback(data){ // < named function defined outside
    console.log(data);
}
```

Essentially what you did is you took the whole inline function, defined it outside, and gave it a name `callback`. Then you passed it by this name as an argument where you earlier defined the whole function inline.
<sub>(This is a better practice too IMO. Especially if you find yourself passing inline functions deep down more than one level you can get serious callback hell problem. ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343116/how-to-handle-callbacks-in-a-for-loopnode-js/29349325#29349325)))</sub>

Similarly, `console.log` is also a (named) function, and so you can pass that as an argument too:

```
response.on('data', console.log)
```